# How to install PyTorch on python 3.12.1

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am installing the [DARTS TimeSeries library](https://github.com/unit8co/darts/blob/master/INSTALL.md#enabling-optional-dependencies) but I run into an issue of dependencies installation. In the DARTS installation guide it said if we run into that issue we have to refer to the official installation guide for PyTorch, then try installing Darts again. Then, when I tried to install torch on python 3.12.1 I run into this error :

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch.

How to solve that?

I am using PyCharm as Python code editor.

I tried a `pip install darts` and it did not install all the packages and encounter this error  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [136 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=64.0
        Obtaining dependency information for setuptools>=64.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages
```

Then, I tried to install torch with `pip install torch` and encountered this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: Did you try to change your Python version? I tried with Anaconda python=3.7 and it worked. Also, try to install Prophet as Darts needs this as a dependency.

Answer (score 5):

Both packages [darts](https://pypi.org/project/darts/#data) and [pytorch](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#data) currently supports Python versions 3.8 - 3.11 but you're using Python 3.12.1 To resolve your issue, install a supported python version and use virtual environments to manage projects that requires specific python versions. For example, you can create a Python 3.10 virtual environment and `pip install darts` there.

**EDIT:**
User @jkr pointed out that pytorch now supports Python 3.11 as can be seen in the [official docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Comment: pytorch supports up to python 3.11 currently

Comment: Please look at the supported programming languages here as at today https://pypi.org/project/torch/#data. It says C++, Python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. No mention of 3.11 officially.

Comment: here is the official documentation, which states that python 3.8-3.11 is supported now https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/. similarly, if you look at the pytorch package on conda, you will see that 3.11 is available there too https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files

Comment: Ok seen and thanks for pointing that out. Any idea when this support happened and why it hasn't been updated on PyPi? Will edit the answer now.

Comment: pytorch 1.13.0 was the first to support python 3.11. that label on pypi would have to be updated by hand, so i wouldn't rely on it. i usually check the "Download files" link for which python versions are available. for example: https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files

Comment: Ok, got it. Yeah it makes sense to look at that

Answer (score 0):

Installation of Darts library using Anaconda:

Step 1: Install Anaconda and launch the Anaconda prompt from the start menu.

Step 2: Enter the following code to create an environment and activate it:
conda create --name darts python=3.7
conda activate darts

Step 3: We install the various libraries required by darts in this environment; it may take some time; simply be patient.
conda install -c conda-forge -c pytorch pip fbprophet pytorch

Step 4: Install the second section:
conda install -c conda-forge -c pytorch pip fbprophet pytorch cpuonly

Step 5: Install darts
pip install darts

If the installation fails, enter：
conda install prophet
Then, once the installation is complete, enter:
pip install darts

step 6: Connect the environment to your PyCharm IDE and run your project
File> Settings> Project Interpreter> Project Interpreter> Show all>+>VirtualEnv Environment > Existing Environment > Navigate to the location of the darts environment on your PC (for example: D:\Anaconda3\envs\darts)> python.exe